# How to interpret this, does variable "i" in the right will be evaluated firstly?

Tags: c++

what I want to do is to copy elements in A to B manually, I previous thought that code 1 and code 2 should have the same functionality, but the results show that, code 2 is correct, code 1 will result in vector B as {-1,3,4}.
I think this is because in `B[i]=A[i++]` the variable "i" in the right is evaluated firstly, then the left, am I right? This code was observed in a textbook, so i think it is true as least in some cases(e.g. under some compilers).
Is it recommended to writing code like code 1? Can you give me some explanations?

```
int main() {
    vector<int> A{2, 3, 4};
    vector<int> B{-1, -1, -1};

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; B[i] = A[i++]); // 1

    // for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) B[i] = A[i]; // 2

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) cout << B[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whichever textbook offered this as an example, you should throw it away and get a better textbook.

Comment: Regardless of the fact that order of operations is (mostly) implementation defined, please just don't write code like this.

Comment: No, you are not right.   There are plenty of lousy textbooks out there that provide terrible code, and even incorrectly represent what the effects of that code will be.   You have clearly obtained one of those lousy textbooks.   The order of evaluation of `B[i]` and `A[i++]` is unspecified, not left to right as you interpret.   Even if, somehow, such code was to become well-specified, such code would not be recommended (except by coders who attach some spurious value to cryptic code, even if they are not sure what it does).

Comment: Before the C++17 standard, the code has undefined behaviour. Using C++17, the code will be *guaranteed* to display the behaviour you note: the RHS of the assignment is evaluated *completely* (with all its consequences) *before* the assignment is performed, or even before the LHS is parsed. *(Well, other than the UB caused by accessing an invalid element with `B[i]`.)*

Answer (score 3):

Until C++17 it was an [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub):

> Between the previous and next sequence point, the prior value of a
> scalar object that is modified by the evaluation of the expression,
> must be accessed only to determine the value to be stored. If it is
> accessed in any other way.

```
cout << i << i++; // undefined behavior (until C++17)
a[i] = i++; // undefined behavior (until C++17)
```

(From [cppreference eval-order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)).

From C++17, the RHS evaluated completely before the LHS, which means in your example you get the behavior you described.

```
B[1] = A[0];
B[2] = A[1];
B[3] = A[2]; // Pay attention to the index out of range here.
```

You could see the error using [vector::at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) instead of [vector::operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; B.at(i) = A[i++]);
```

`at` is a safe access to the vector elements, while checking for errors. After evaluation, this line will throw the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 3) >= this->size() (which is 3)
```

To fix it, evaluate `i++` at LHS:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; B.at(i++) = A[i]);
```

A simplified behavior example is:

```
int i = 5;
i = i++; // RHS result: 5 & i incremented to 6. LHS result: i (which is now 6) equal to RHS (which is 5).
```

Result: `i = 5`.

**But the best way to handle those situations is simply don't write code like this one. You don't benefit anything from code like this one, and you open a door for long term latent bugs.**

Comment: You say "you described" `B[1] = A[0]; B[2] = A[1]; B[3] = A[2];` but in fact what he says is `B[1] = A[1]; B[2] = A[2];` which is even more bizarre.

Comment: @Manuel "I think this is because in B[i]=A[i++] the variable "i" in the right is evaluated firstly, then the left, am I right?" - This is what the OP described.

Comment: @KorelK yes, you are right, but the result you show is `B{-1,2,3}` while OP says `B{-1,3,4}` which is really strange.

Comment: @Manuel Two options: 1. The OP have a typo there. 2. Modifying an element which is out of range is a UB, anything could happen, including this strange result.

Comment: yes, yes, you are right. I don't say you are wrong. I'm just surprised by the OP result. In fact my result is exactly as you described in your response.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not recommended.

The evaluation of the side effect of the Post-increment operator is only guaranteed to happen before the next sequence point, but you can't know when it will be sequenced.

In your case the side effect happens before the assignment so A[0] is assigned to B[1].

You can read more about the details here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Answer (score 1):

I don't obtain the same result with you code. I'm using g++ 8.3 (with and without `-std=c++2a`) (same result in goldbolt gcc 10.1).

The result I have is `-1 2 3` not `-1 3 4`.

In any case I have even a warning:

```
main.cc:80:38: warning: operation on ‘i’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; B[i] = A[i++]) {
```

That said, it seems (g++ in this case) gets (idx 0) the value to be assigned (2), increments the index (post increment after getting the value) and sets the value to `B` (`B[1] = 2`).

What definitely has no sense is `-1 3 4`.

In any case, as @buszkiraly says, it depends on the sequence (which as others commented isn't guaranteed.)

> Between the previous and next sequence point, the prior value of a scalar object that is modified by the evaluation of the expression, must be accessed only to determine the value to be stored. If it is accessed in any other way, the behavior is undefined.

In our case:

> The value computation of the built-in post-increment and post-decrement operators is sequenced before its side-effect

so `A[i++]` is `A[i]` (`i = 0`; `A[0] = 2`).

then goes the post-increment and `i = 1`:

> [8)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) The side effect (modification of the left argument) of the built-in assignment operator and of all built-in compound assignment operators is sequenced after the value computation (but not the side effects) of both left and right arguments, and is sequenced before the value computation of the assignment expression (that is, before returning the reference to the modified object)

which gives us:

`B[i]` is `B[1]`, `B[1] = A[0]`.

So no "Is it recommended to writing code like code 1?" No:

> Because of the side-effects involved, built-in increment and decrement operators must be used with care to avoid undefined behavior due to violations of [sequencing rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).